# jQuery Mobile Panel : Page can't load

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, panel

I was working with jQuery Mobile platform to develop a mobile website. For which I have to use panels. I was able to make a working panel https://jsfiddle.net/VQmsw/, but when I embed this code in my actual file it is giving some page loading problem.

```
<html>
    
    <head>
        <title>Panels | Jquery Mobile</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <!-- @ Page=menu -->
        <div data-role="page" id="menu">
            <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel" class="main_nav" data-display="push" data-dismissible="true" data-theme="a">
                <div class="nav_profile">
                    <div class="nav_name">
                        <h3>user</h3>
                        <p>2 active threads</p>
                    </div>
                    <!--/nav_name-->
                </div>
                <!--/nav_profile-->
            </div>
            <!-- /panel -->
            <div data-role="header" class="ui-header ui-bar-c" data-fullscreen="true" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
                <a href="#myPanel" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c"></a>
                <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Events</h1>
                <a href="#myPanel" data-icon="menu" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c"></a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content"></div>
        </div>
        <!--/menu-->
    </body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/57Mfu/. I know that in fiddle you need to give external resources but the same code doesn't work normally as well.

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: because in this fiddle you're loading jQuery and jQuery Mobile twice. http://jsfiddle.net/57Mfu/. check **External Resources** the panel on the left side, remove them and the ones in `<head>` and it'll work just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ytk6s/

Answer (score 1):

Use Latest stable versions of jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery-Mobile 1.3.1.

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3. 1.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this with jquery 1.9.1 instead of 2.0.  I experienced a similar problem earlier--it worked on jsfiddle but now in my code--then I used all the correct versions of jquery and jquery-mobile, and it worked like a charm.